# How can i solve a Dotnet build Error "namespace name 'Azure' could not be found"?

Tags: c#, .net, azure

I am running a simple .NET application that connects to Azure Event Hubs and send sample data.
Unfortunately when i hit " dotnet run" i get the following errors:

```
C:\Users\[...]\EventHubSampleSendData\Program.cs(1,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Azure' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\Users\[...]\SendSampleData.csproj]
```

It looks like dotnet cannot recognize the Azure library "(using) Azure.Messaging.EventHubs) inside the Program.cs

I tried the command "dotnet add package Azure.Messaging.EventHubs" but it gives also errors ( The project does not support adding package references through the add package command.)

project:
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/event-hubs-dotnet-ingest/tree/master/EventHubSampleData/EventHubSampleSendData

Comment: restore packages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to re-intsall or restore all the packages that you have installed while creating your project. The way to do it is:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

restore the dotnet packages, run `dotnet restore` in your src directory. If that doesn't solve the issue check if the specified package is added otherwise you can add it through nuget.